# Test for Firefox being hidden in OS X

Tags: macos, firefox-addon, jsctypes

Is there a way I test to see if Firefox windows are hidden in OS X via the "Hide Firefox" (Command-H) option?  Enumerating using nsIWindowMediator says that the hidden attribute is false and the windowState is STATE_NORMAL for these hidden windows in OS X.  Thanks!

Comment: hey man did you figure this one out? i think it is doable with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179766/how-to-test-if-window-is-currently-focused

Comment: Didn't figure this out directly, but I was able to track each window via:

`window.addEventListener
    ('activate', PersonaSwitcher.onWindowActivate, false);
window.addEventListener
    ('deactivate', PersonaSwitcher.onWindowDeactivate, false);`

and keeping track of whether any window was activated. And in the end, didn't really need this functionality after all... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know but heres a way that might help you figure out.

install this [addon from github](https://github.com/Noitidart/cDumpJSM/blob/master/bootstrap.js)

and then in scratchpad in browser environment run `Cu.import('chrome://cdumpjsm/content/cDump.jsm'); cDump(window,{depth:0})` when hidden, then save that file. then show the window then run cDump again, then diff the files

Comment: Try depth of 1 but don't go more that cDump procedure is still experimental so it locks up the browser if you go deeper than 1 on a window object I think.

Comment: I was able to run it when the window was exposed -- the scratchpad disappears along with the application when Command-H is used, so I called it from a method using a timer when it was hidden.  No differences.  Strange.  It did lock up when called twice for some reason.  I'm going to do some experimenting on Windows and Linux to see how they behave.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem that cDump module is a work in progress, author needs to make it not crash when dumping window, he knows of the issue. I don't have a Mac otherwise I would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(window)` or if you dont have access to thew indow object `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log(Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'))` then in browser console go and click '[object ChromeWindow]' and then it will print all its enumerable and non-enumerable properties.

Maybe it will show something in here differently when it's hidden I'm not sure.

[image: VariableViewer in Browser Console]

Answer (score 0):

Ok at long last here is your solution. js-ctypes using objective-c:

Tested on OS 10.9

[GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-OSXHidden.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/cb8e39bdf98567f11e86)

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');
var objc = ctypes.open(ctypes.libraryName('objc'));

// types
var id = ctypes.voidptr_t;
var SEL = ctypes.voidptr_t;
var BOOL = ctypes.signed_char;

// constants
var nil = ctypes.voidptr_t(0);

//common functions
var objc_getClass = objc.declare('objc_getClass', ctypes.default_abi, id, ctypes.char.ptr);
var sel_registerName = objc.declare('sel_registerName', ctypes.default_abi, SEL, ctypes.char.ptr);
var objc_msgSend = objc.declare('objc_msgSend', ctypes.default_abi, id, id, SEL, '...');

//common selectors
var alloc = sel_registerName('alloc');
var init = sel_registerName('init');
var release = sel_registerName('release');

//now using docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSApplication/hidden

// pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]
var NSAutoreleasePool = objc_getClass('NSAutoreleasePool');
var pool = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(NSAutoreleasePool, alloc), init);

// NSApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
var NSApplication = objc_getClass('NSApplication');
var sharedApplication = sel_registerName('sharedApplication');
var NSApp = objc_msgSend(NSApplication, sharedApplication);

// [NSApp isHidden]
var isHidden = sel_registerName('isHidden');
var objc_msgSend_returnBool = objc.declare('objc_msgSend', ctypes.default_abi, BOOL, id, SEL, '...'); //this is return value because `isHidden` returns a BOOL per the docs
var rez_isHidden = objc_msgSend_returnBool(NSApp, isHidden);
console.info('rez_isHidden:', rez_isHidden, rez_isHidden.toString(), uneval(rez_isHidden));

if (rez_isHidden == 0) {
    console.log('Firefox is HIDDEN!');
} else if (rez_isHidden == 1) {
    console.log('Firefox is showing.');
} else {
    console.warn('rez_isHidden was not 0 or 1, this should never happen, if it did, objc should error and crash the browser');
}

// [pool release]
objc_msgSend(pool, release);

objc.close();
```

Credit to @arai for teaching me objc jsctypes! When no one else would the guy spoon fed me!!! More people should spoon feed each other!