# How to test if window is currently focused

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way to test if a window is currently focused? I know I can do this with addEventListener of activated on the window, and use a global var to track it, but the thing is I need to test this on startup of my addon, so this is before a chance to add any event listeners.

Doing `window == Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null)` will not work because other application windows may be over it. So I guess I need to know if firefox is the currently top most window.

tldr: I need to test if the current window is focused, meaning not just of any other firefox windows, but of all windows on the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With the add-on sdk:

```
require("sdk/window/utils").isFocused(window)
```

## Without the add-on sdk:

```
function isFocused(window) {
  const FM = Cc["@mozilla.org/focus-manager;1"].
                getService(Ci.nsIFocusManager);

  let childTargetWindow = {};
  FM.getFocusedElementForWindow(window, true, childTargetWindow);
  childTargetWindow = childTargetWindow.value;

  let focusedChildWindow = {};
  if (FM.activeWindow) {
    FM.getFocusedElementForWindow(FM.activeWindow, true, focusedChildWindow);
    focusedChildWindow = focusedChildWindow.value;
  }

  return (focusedChildWindow === childTargetWindow);
}

isFocused(window);
```

Comment: Oh wow! This is fantastic! Cross OS too!!  Tested on Ubuntu Mac109 and Win81 superb man thanks!

Comment: Hey @erik, so this is awesome it works great. I currently run through all windows to test if any one of them is focused. Is there a smarter way then iterating all windows to test if anything is focused? Im basically trying to write a function that detects browser lost focus, and then browser got focus. By browser i mean any window of the browser. Thanks!

Comment: Man I use this on contentWindow and domWindow this has been such a handy script thank you man!! (non sdk version here)